# Handling codeigniter application on server

Tags: codeigniter, server

I have CODEIGNITER site live and running successfully on a server, but when I move(copy and paste) the contents in another folder on the same server I am getting 404 page not found error.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Please show what you are doing and any responses being returned, this question needs to be expanded upon.

Comment: Check the log file under application/logs. If there is no recent entry, you are not even get to the framework. If this is the case, check the webserver logs directly. (e.g. Apache: /var/log/apache2/error.log)

Comment: I copy and pasted the contents of A(live) folder to B(new) folder for doing changes, but it seems whenever I try to login using username and password, I am getting this error -Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.1.6

Comment: Make sure you have followed the codeigniter file and class naming method explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming it also could that you may need a htaccess in main directory

Comment: I did check and it seems all the conventions are according to user guide. Can you please elaborate the htaccess, requirement? @wolfgang1983

Comment: give the folder structure where you move the content means for ex public_html/project/folder

Comment: Its, public_html/project_folder/ajax, public_html/project_folder/application, and so on. I am able to load index.php file and then login screen, but whenever I login, it gives me 404 error. @AnandPandey

Comment: can you show your htaccess?

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L], this is from applications folder, and the one in system folder has Deny from all in it. @AnandPandey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Use this htaccess in the project folder not in application folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

If your folder is not follow like that public_html/project_folder
than change here

```
RewriteBase project_folder/
```

Comment: I did, but no use. Still getting the 404 message.

Comment: Make sure this htaccess oustside of application folder and the default htaccess reside in application folder